# Prometheus Error: Collector already registered that provides name: http_client_requests_count

Tags: java, spring, prometheus

I'm seeing this odd Prometheus-related error:

```
RESTful call failed. Cause: Collector already registered that provides name: http_client_requests_count
```

I didn't include a http_client_requests_count metric in my project -- so what gives? Where the heck is this coming from?

Answer (score 6):

I encountered a similar error in my tests, what I ended up doing to fix this error was to:

```
    @BeforeEach
    @AfterEach
    public void cleanup() {
        CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry.clear();
    }
```

Comment: `@AfterEach` should be fine. After adding this annotation, my issue got resolved.

Comment: @AfterEach sufficed for us too. Maybe this is could be helpful to others: we ran into this problem, but the reporting IT test failure was not actually the test causing the problem. We first added it to the reported test which didn't change anything. We then added this to all of our ITs and it fixed it. We then determined by trial and error removing them to single out the test causing the failure.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably due to the context being reloaded, and thus collectors trying to re-register to the static `CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry`.

See more info and work-arounds here: https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/issues/290

Comment: I don't see any workarounds mentioned on the link you provided.

Comment: Definitely don't see any workarounds mentioned in that link, but our error was caused by an external client registering multiple CollectorRegistries.